# mysqli array does not print values properly

Tags: php, sql, mysqli

I'm having trouble printing out the values from my MySQLi query. Here is the db connection class that I am using.

```
class db
{
 public function  __construct() 
    {
    $this->mysqli = new mysqli('localhost', 'root','', 'database');
    if (mysqli_connect_errno())
    {
        printf("Connect failed: %s\n", mysqli_connect_error());
        exit();
    }
}

public function Query($SQL)
{
    $this->SQL = $this->mysqli->real_escape_string($SQL);
    $this->Result = $this->mysqli->query($SQL);
    if ($this->Result == true)
    return true;
    else
    die('Problem with Query: ' . $this->SQL);
}

public function Get($field = NULL)
{
    if ($field == NULL)
    {
        $data = array();
        while ($row = $this->Result->fetch_assoc())
        {
            $data[] = $row;
        }
    }
    else
    {
        $row = $this->Result->fetch_assoc();
        $data = $row[$field];
    }

    $this->Result->close();
    return $data;
}

public function __destruct()
{
    $this->mysqli->close();
}
}
```

Running a query

```
$db = new db;
$db->Query("SELECT * FROM tblclients WHERE clientid = $this->id");
$result = $db->Get();
echo $result['clientid'];
```

I'm getting error

```
PHP Notice:  Undefined index: clientid
```

However I know the values are getting passed to the $results array when I run

```
print_r ($result);
```

I get this returned

```
Array ( [0] => Array ( [clientid] => 2 [firstname] => John [lastname] => Doe [dob] => 1962-05-08))
```

For what its worth, if I try `echo $db->Get('firstname');` everything works. Been banging my head against the wall for a while now, any help appreciated.

Comment: You have to go one lever deeper, to $result[0].

Comment: $result[0]['clientid'];

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As you can see you have an array inside another array. To get what you need you need to go like this:

```
$result[0]['clientid'];
```

So what we're doing here is you are first calling the `$result` variable which contains an array with an index of `[0]`, then this array contains the column names from your query (ex: `['clientid']`).

So you basically have to go deeper than `$result['clientid']` to get your data from the database by firstly calling the array that contains those keys from the database.

To un-nest that array, do something like:

```
$result = $db->Get();
$normal_result = 0;

foreach ($result as $value)
{
    $normal_result = $value;
}
```

You can use this inside your method, so you'll get normal results only in the future.

Comment: Appreciate the help, makes sense now.